# Cannot store a long type variable in a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap, long-integer

So I tried to store a big integer number in a HashMap like below:

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class MyClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            HashMap<String, Long> phonebook = new HashMap<String, Long>();
            phonebook.put("John", 85972252904);
            Integer a = phonebook.get("John");
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

The code didn't work. Eclipse told me that "the literal 85972252904 of type int is out of range". So I wanna ask:

1) What is my problem here?
2) Furthermore, HashMap only accepts Classes as its parameters, and I just found out that the class "Long" is deprecated. What am I supposed to use to store a big integer as an object now?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The range error is nothing to do with the map. If you try and use the literal `85972252904` anywhere you would get a similar error.

Comment: `85972252904l` and `Long a = phonebook.get("John");`

Comment: Phone number isn't actually quite a number. It's close, but you're still better off using some other way of storing it.

Comment: Class `Long` is not deprecated, where did you get that idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add an 'L' to the literal so it's treated as a long:
`85972252904L`

Comment: also problem here `Integer a = phonebook.get("John");`

Comment: Agreed, that will get a class cast exception

Comment: thanks, it worked. The Integer part is when I tried to change it to an int to see if it still works, and then forgot to change it back before posting.